# repositioning a <p> from a jQueryUI dialog to centerstage for CSS Print

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using a jQueryUI Dialog command to popup a `<p>` and wish to print just the text of the `<p>` using the `media="print"` declarative

html code::

```
<div class="jPajxDialog">
  <p class="print">
    Some Text
  </p>
<div>
```

I have tried:
CSS code::

```
@charset "UTF-8";

body {visibility:hidden;}
.print {visibility:visible;}
.noprint {visibility: hidden;}

p.print {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 15px auto;
}
```

Comment: Do you want that “Some Text” is only visible on printed media (and not on the screen) or do you want “Some Text” to be always visible and get rid of the parent `<div class="jPajxDialog">` when printing?

Comment: always visible, and to get rid of the parent and become absolutly positioned at the top center of the page on print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide something when printing, you should use "display: none" in css. Just keep in mind that if you make a parent "display: none", all of his children will also NOT be displayed, even if you did a "display: block;" on the child.

You might want to review your html structure so that pieces of information that you want to hide will not be a parent of what you want to keep, that is if you want to have a cross browser compatible solution.

For example,

```
<div>
  <div class="noprint"> Site header </div>
  <div>
    <div class="noprint"> Site menu </div>
    <div class="print"> the content you wish to print </div>
    <div class="noprint"> Site footer </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css media="print"

```
.noprint { display: none; }
.print { display: block; }
```

Comment: Also, "visibility: hidden" is bad because the content will still use the same space (width/height) as if it was visible, hence the "display: none". Finally, what you did could not work because you set "visibility: hidden" on the body, which is the parent of every other tag in your page, and that was hiding all content on your page.